# Naming tables using middle dot in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database

Could it cause problems to name a table using middle dots, like this:

```sql
tbl_prod·prov;
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it that way? :)

Comment: Yes, it could. It's likely to hurt your reputation as a developer if someone else takes a look at your database/code in the future. (It's also time to ditch the long-outdated `tbl_` naming convention.)

Comment: In principle, nothing.

Comment: @ceejayoz, That is a very arrogant and subjective point of view, which I do not think can be considered good practice either. As far as I know, not everyone uses the same conventions in a strict manner, but adapts them in the way that they consider most appropriate, right? Thank you anyway ;)

Comment: My standard for code is that it should generate as few "what the fuck?"s as possible. Seeing a middot used in a table name would most certainly increment the count. `tbl_` in a table name is less of a "WTF" and more of a . It's just redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules are explained at [Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html):

> Identifiers are converted to Unicode internally. They may contain these characters:
>
> - Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:
>
>   - ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)
>   - Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF
> - Permitted characters in quoted identifiers include the full Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), except U+0000:
>
>   - ASCII: U+0001 .. U+007F
>   - Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF
> - ASCII NUL (U+0000) and supplementary characters (U+10000 and higher) are not permitted in quoted or unquoted identifiers.
> - Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.
> - Database, table, and column names cannot end with space characters.

The `·` character is [U+00B7 MIDDLE DOT](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b7/index.htm) so it fits the definition for *Extended* in quoted identifiers.

Said that, I can think of two potential problems:

- Object names sometimes needs to be mapped to filesystem objects. We can speculate that MySQL has done things right in all supported platforms but it makes me feel uneasy.
- If you happen to run a SQL query in a client/connection that's not correctly configured, or you paste the query from the clipboard, you risk using the wrong character.

Comment: Thank you, @Álvaro González. Very useful information :)